# using @DrawableRes in an enum kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an enum class like this:

```
 enum class WayPointStatusEnum(val id: Int,
                          @StringRes val stringRes: Int,
                          @DrawableRes val imageRes: Int,
                          val listener: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
NEW_WALK(1,R.string.new_walk_status, R.drawable.ic_baseline_accessibility_new),
PAUSED_WALK(2,R.string.paused_walk_status, R.drawable.ic_baseline_accessible),
SAVED_WALK(3,R.string.saved_walk_status, R.drawable.ic_baseline_save_alt),
ACTIVE_WALK(4,R.string.active_walk_status, R.drawable.ic_baseline_accessible_forward),
WAYPOINT(5,R.string.waypoint_status, R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_pin_circle),
}
```

I am using it in a model like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="model"
        type="com.wfs.android.walkinjinni.datamodels.Waypoint" />
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_walk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/save_to_sheet"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:drawableStart="@{model.status.imageRes}"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/walk_status"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/save_walk"
            android:text="@{model.status.stringRes}"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/save_walk"

            android:text="@{model.name}"
            android:hint="@string/hint_location"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationAddressTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locationNameTextView"
            android:text="@{model.distance.toString()}"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My issue is that the @stringRes seems to work fine, I get the text based on the enum as expected but for the image in the button it never shows up.  I tried just grabbing the draw-able from the resources folder and it worked fine.  Does anyone know what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting it on ImageView to make sure this is not a problem with TextView compound drawables.

Comment: as the states I put the image from the enum on the button already and it was fine. are you talking about something other than that?

Comment: I mean try using your enum on an `ImageView` with `android:src="@{model.status.imageRes}"` to see it that works.

Comment: it does not show in the image view either.  I confirmed the image view shows by adding one from drawables

Comment: Hey @keepTrackOfYourStack, are you also using this annotation on your method return? If not have you tried it by adding a method for your `imageRes` and adding the same annotation to this method.

Comment: not sure i understand, there is no method return it is used in xml in the model [and the string resource works]  But this is the first time I have tried this.  can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, but its kind of frustrating, none of the sample code I found went as far as showing how to use the enum in the xml.  This only works on api 21 and greater.  Luckily that's what I have otherwise I guess I would need a binding adapter

```
   android:drawableStart="@{context.getDrawable(model.status.imageRes)}"
```

I guess it does not resolve into a draw-able just a resourceId.  Am i missing something?